# Identify SMD component with marking "0307 AE 1930"

Tags: identification

Can anyone identify the SMD component circled in the below photograph?

It has the following marking:

```
0307 
AE
1930
```

It appears twice and the components are labeled `QF5` and `QF6` on the PCB.

[image: photograph of PCB]

Comment: looks like a FET

Comment: *Q*F5 and 6, the *Q* helps signify it as a transistor.

Answer (score 3):

[Infineon BSF450NE7NH3](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSF450NE7NH3-DS-v02_03-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30433a047ba0013a687e2ae403da) in CanPAK S package.